# booleen mask for datatypes using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i know we can use say df['col'] >= 1 to return a booleen mask of true/false values for a specific pandas df column, but is there a way to filter for data types?

I'd like to filter out NaN values in a column that has both string and NaN values.

Comment: `df.dropna(subset='col')`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `NaN`'s with `df['col'].isna()`.  Returns a boolean mask.